# omreport missing after CentOS 5.4 yum update

Tags: centos, dell, yum, update

I just ran `yum -y update` and now I get

```
omreport: command not found
```

> uname -a Linux smtp.alexx.net 2.6.18-164.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Nov 3
>   16:18:27 EST 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

found it

```
ln -s /opt/dell/srvadmin/bin/omreport /usr/local/sbin/omreport
```